# What does the charset param do in IOUtils.copy()?

Tags: java

I'm not a Java developer but just have to understand what some Java is doing.

I have some code `IOUtils.copy(InputStream a, Writer b, "ISO-8859-1")` or words to that effect

The docs for this method say that "inputEncoding - the encoding to use for the input stream, null means platform default".

As I understand it this is just saying that a is expected to be in ISO-8859-1. It is not doing any kind of conversion? What is the significance of this. What would happen if the inputstream was encoded as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it this is just saying that a is expected to be in ISO-8859-1.

Well, it's expecting the *data in the stream that `a` refers to* to be textual data encoded in ISO-8859-1.

> It is not doing any kind of conversion?

Yes it is. It's interpreting the *binary data* read from the stream as text in the given encoding, and then writing that *textual data* to the writer. (At least, that's what I assume given the method name.)

> What would happen if the inputstream was encoded as UTF-8?

If the data were actually textual data encoded in UTF-8, then bogus data would be written to the writer (`b`). Each byte would be converted to a character (as ISO-8859-1 has one byte per character) and then that character would be written to the writer. If the data contained a character which was encoded into UTF-8 as multiple bytes, the writer would receive multiple characters for that single original character.

Basically, if you get the wrong encoding, the data can easily be garbled. It's like trying to play a WAV file as if it were an MP3 file - except without the safeguards which make it *obviously* broken in that case...

Answer (score 2):

Java has two kinds of classes/interfaces for I/O: Streams (`InputStream`, `OutputStream`) and `Readers`/`Writers`.

**Streams** are for reading and writing binary data (bytes). **Readers** and **writers** are for reading and writing text (characters).

Characters need to be converted from or to bytes by using a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Your `IOUtils.copy` method needs to know how to interpret the bytes in the `InputStream` to convert them into characters that can be written to the `Writer`.

If the `InputStream` contains sequences of bytes that are not valid in the character set that you supply, you might get strange effects (strange characters being written, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Text is represented in computers by the pair (bytes, encoding). The API you mentioned mixes the [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) API, which is intened for all byte streams (not only text, also PNG images for instance, or ZIP archives, which has methods like `read(byte[] b)`) and the [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) API, which instead deals with String (in fact has methods like `write(String)`)

That method has to know how to build a `String` from the byte stream, and that's what the charset paramter is for. If you don't specify one, the default charset of the platform is assumed, but a charset **is always needed** when you want to build text from a byte stream. A given array of bytes may represent different text when different charset are used for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

A [writer](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) isn't just a stream of bytes, it deals with characters and strings, that's why the `copy` function needs a charset, to build the reader from the input stream in order to read characters.

Here's the `copy` implementation when you pass a writer :

```
1124    public static long More ...copyLarge(Reader input, Writer output) throws IOException {
1125        char[] buffer = new char[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
1126        long count = 0;
1127        int n = 0;
1128        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
1129            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
1130            count += n;
1131        }
1132        return count;
1133    }
```

You see it read chars, which is only possible if you know the charset (remember that the number of bytes per character is charset dependent).

Answer (score 0):

The CharSet tells to interpret the bytes given by the InputStream as values given by the table ISO-8859-1

Here's the table values
[ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29)