# OutputStreamWriter constructor: how does the encoding work?

Tags: java, encoding

I am not a Java developer. I just have to understand what this constructor is doing:

```
x = new OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream output, "UTF-8") 
x.write(some string)
```

I've simplified the code a bit hopefully to highlight my essential question.

The docs says:

> Characters written to it are encoded into bytes using a specified charset.

Does this mean that the string in x is now encoded into UTF-8? Does this do conversion? If the string passed to .write is say an ISO-8859-1 string will this be converted? How will it know?

Comment: How is this different from your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661075/what-does-the-charset-param-do-in-ioutils-copy

Comment: In java strings are technically *always* UTF-16. In my opinion you can reason about them as if they have no effective encoding; they are strings of characters and only when you write or read them to or from a source of bytes you need an encoding.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Well, unless you have characters outside the BMP...

Comment: @JonSkeet True, that is an exception that I try to ignore really hard ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark Rottevell. Because the questions relate to two entirely different class and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the string in x is now encoded into UTF-8?

No. It means that when the writer receives a string (which is *always* effectively in UTF-16) it is encoded into bytes using the specified encoding, and then written to the underlying `OutputStream`.

The important point to note is that an `OutputStream` is asked to write bytes, whereas a `Writer` is asked to write text. The encoding specifies the conversion applied to the text data in order to get binary data, basically.

Comment: As by design java clearly separates **text**, `String/~Writer/~Reader`, which always is in Unicode so to cover all possible characters. Whereas `byte[]/~OutputStream/~InputStream` is **binary data**, and might represent text if one knows the encoding used. **String = byte[] + encoding**